# How to get cell data from Excel in F# (with appropriate typing)

Tags: f#, excel-interop, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-fake

I am trying to read some data from excel. The value is being stored as an obj type, but when I try to cast it to an int or double type I get a type error.

My code:

```
open System
open System.Data
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
open Microsoft.Office.Interop

let xl = new Excel.ApplicationClass()
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(@"Y:\Test.xlsx")
let Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets.["Sheet1"] :?> Excel.Worksheet
let tr= Sheet1 .Cells.[1,3]:?> int
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
     at <StartupCode$FSI_0018>.$FSI_0018.main@() in Y:\Script2.fsx:line 20
      Stopped due to error
```

Comment: if i change cells to range, casting work fine `let tr:double = unbox(Sheet1.Range("c1").Value2)`

Comment: What does `Cells.[1,3]` return (which data type?

Comment: WorksheetClass.Cells returns Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range see [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetclass.cells.aspx)

Comment: @HaagenDaz better use range directly, Cells returns Range so doing `let tr:double = (Sheet1.Cells.[1,3] :?> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2 |> unbox` is circling around

Answer (score 2):

Try casting your cell selection to a `Range` first, then do the value type casting after you've got the cell value:

```
let xl = new Excel.ApplicationClass()
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(@"Y:\Test.xlsx")
let sheet1 = wb.Worksheets.["Sheet1"] :?> Excel.Worksheet
let cell = sheet1.Cells.[1,3] :?> Excel.Range
let value = int (string cell.Value2)
```

You can take more care with the final casting step if you are expecting varying data.